# Using "inverse" for class.weights in R package {e1071}

Tags: r

In the new version 1.7-0 of the R package e1071, it is said that class.weights argument of svm() now accepts "inverse". However, I couldn't find any example usage of this. What should I put in exactly in class.weights to utilize this new feature? I tried class.weights="inverse" and a named vector of "inverse" with corresponding class names. Both didn't work.

Comment: https://github.com/cran/e1071/blob/bb30e53080210817e41e8f45397c9b064de9280d/R/svm.R#L216. Seems the correct usage is class.weights="inverse". A quick bypass is to use class.weights=1/table(y).